# VB.NET Transparent Panel

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a transparent panel. I want add a panel to the center of a form. This panel should result in darkness.

How can I add a transparent panel to my form without a background picture?

[image]

Comment: By default there is no background picture in a panel.  Are you saying that you want there to be stuff behind the panel that you can see?  Can you explain a bit more of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Im wanna see behind of panel with a darkness color. Like this ;

https://imgur.com/UkSKUj3

Answer (score 1):

1)Set the background image of the form to the picture you want as a background and set the background image layout to 'stretch' as shown below.

[image]

2)Add a panel control.

3)Size the panel control to cover most of the form.

4)Add the code below to the form load event.

```
Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(185, 0, 0, 0)
```

5)Set form border style to 'none'

[image]

6)Add a button to the panel

7)Set the buttons Flat Style, Border Size and Forecolor as shown below.

[image]

8)Add the following code to the form load event.

```
Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(75, 240, 240, 240)
```

9)Compile and there you go

[image]

Note:You can use the same method for other controls on the form but remember that it will only be the background image of the form that shows in any control.  In other words, you can't stack controls on top of each other and see the bottom control because the background of the foremost control will be the background image of the form not the control immediately behind it.

Comment: Since you are a new contributor I am going to give you some advice.  You should not be rude to the people that are trying to help you on here.  You posted a picture (imgur.com/UkSKUj3 ) of what you wanted to achieve and I posted an answer of how to achieve that.  If that is not truly what you want to achieve then the problem is with your question, not with my answer.  Make your question more succinct and perhaps you will get the answer you seek.  None of us are paid to post answers on here so we should not be subjected to any of of your "Come on dude......:(" type remarks.

Comment: I will give a advice to you Jamie , dont even give answer if you didnt read the problem.